# Agora Voice Call Disconnects after 40 seconds

Tags: reactjs, react-native, agora.io

I developed app in react native and for voice calls use Agora. When I connects the call I am able to hear voice for 40 seconds and after that voice loss.  When I saw agora analytics it showed graph saying choppy audio. Can anyone help to let me know why voice losts after 40 seconds is there any setting I am missing? Bundle of thanks in advance

Comment: Is the app in background when this happens? Is this noticed on both Android and iOS?

Comment: It happens both Andriod and IOS, In IOS we configured settings when app goes in background. When I saw agora analytics it says Choppy Audio (Causes  Network Disconnection) but it keep on happening exactly after 40 second. This frequency of occurrence is not making any sense

Comment: Can you share some code to reproduce the issue? My initial assumption was that the app gets terminated due to it being in the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't seem to reproduce the error using the [demo app](https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/Agora-RN-Quickstart). The app terminating can be because of a few reasons, it can be cleaned up by the system if it's in background for a while. It can even be quit due to a memory leak. To narrow it down check your app logs.